# Segmentation fault in Simple Scan, XSane and scanimage

Tags: ubuntu, sane

I've been using Simple Scan on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS for a couple years now, but today I'm not able to launch it anymore. It opens it window and immediately crashes. When I try to use CLI instead I'm having this message:

```
bugchk_free(ptr=(nil))@modelinf.c(464)
Abandon (core dumped)
```

I've tried to used Xsane or scanimage instead, but I'm having the exact same issue. Skanlite seems to work though (but it is not able to recognize my scanner).

Here are my libsane packages (from `dpkg -l | grep sane`):

```
ii  libsane-common                             1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2.2                  all          API library for scanners -- documentation and support files
ii  libsane-hpaio:amd64                        3.17.10+repack0-5                                amd64        HP SANE backend for multi-function peripherals
ii  libsane1:amd64                             1.0.27-1~experimental3ubuntu2.2                  amd64        API library for scanners
ii  sane-utils                                 1.0.30-bionic1                                   amd64        API library for scanners -- utilities
```

I've tried to upgrade those from `rolfbesnch/sane-release` PPA, but this doesn't seem to solve my issue. Should I try to use `rolfbensch/sane-git` PPA instead?

Thanks,

Comment: I have the same problem.  Sometimes I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, and sometimes `Bus error (core dumped)`, and sometimes `Out of memory Aborted (core dumped)`.  Didn't happen a week ago.

Comment: I did `sudo apt remove sane-airscan`, and that fixed the problem.  Maybe there was a bug introduced with the latest sane-airscan update.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @aswine, but I do not have the issue anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some updates seem to have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd fixed segfault for my "Pantum M6500" in `scanimage -L`:

```
$ scanimage -L
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

by removing `tcp ...` entry from `/etc/sane.d/pantum6500.conf`

```
tcp M6500 9200
```

I've found by `trace scanimage -L` that scanimage reading `/etc/sane.d/pantum6500.conf` and than trying to bind TCP port and than segfault occurs.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with segmentation fault in Xsane with my HP4200 USB scanner after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from Ubuntu 18.04.

I found many google suggestions to no avail. I configured and compiled the back end for the HP4200 and it was still crashing.

I enabled the debug messages in the source code and found that the debug messages were telling me that it was crashing always in the same place

a subroutine called `do_fine_calibration` in the `hp4200.c` file. In that subroutine `memset` is called and it appeared that that was where the crash occurred.

If `memset` is called with a null pointer it tries to access non existent memory. I tried to find if Ubuntu 20.04 did something different in memory management but found nothing.

Anyway it seemed that this code was setting up a large array called registro for which a pointer didn't seem to exist!

I'm not a memory management guru but after some study i decided to change the registro declaration to set it to 0 when declared
(about line 1377 - `int registro[30][5460 * 3] = {0};` with my change)

and then eliminate the code section (line 1496 - about 1505) that memsets the  registro array to 0.

After a re `./configuration`, `make sudo make install` and firing up scanimage for a scan, lo and behold the motor took off and began to scan again!